# Is there a way to create a datepicker widget in Azure databricks?

Tags: python-3.x, widget, plotly, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to implement a datepicker/calendar in databricks. So far I could come up with ***dbutils.widgets.text*** to take date as input. Although it works, but I wanted to come up with a datepicker. In the databricks widgets documentation. I could find only 4 types - text, dropdown, combobox, multiselect. So is there some way with which a calendar/datepicker could be implemented. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are **only 4 widgets** as given below

Widget types

4 types of widgets:

•   **text:** Input a value in a text box.

•   **dropdown:** Select a value from a list of provided values.

•   **combobox:** Combination of text and dropdown. Select a value from a provided list or input one in the text box.

•   **multiselect:** Select one or more values from a list of provided values.

Refer [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/widgets#widget-types)

However you can **select year by using dropdown widget** as shown below

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have seen the documentation example for this dropdown year, but I wanted something like panel datepicker - a calendar dropdown with date ,month, year

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible since the Databricks Runtime 11.0, thanks to the integration of Jupyter's ipywidget :
https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/ipywidgets.html

Here the link to the available widgets list :
https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/7.7.0/examples/Widget%20List.html